# Unable to resolve: The class 'DatabaseHelper' doesn't have a constructor named '_privateConstructor'

Tags: android, flutter, android-studio, dart

I am unable to resolve The class `DatabaseHelper` doesn't have a constructor named `_privateConstructor`.  Try invoking a different constructor, or define a constructor named `_privateConstructor`. error, in my provider, even though it has been initialized in the database.
Database Code:

```
import 'package:sqflite/sqflite.dart';
import 'package:path/path.dart';

import '../models/medication_model.dart';

class DatabaseHelper {
  static final DatabaseHelper instance = DatabaseHelper._privateConstructor();

  static Database? _database;

  DatabaseHelper._privateConstructor();


  Future<Database> get database async {
    if (_database != null) return _database!;
    _database = await _initDatabase();
    return _database!;
  }

  Future<Database> _initDatabase() async {
    final String path = await getDatabasesPath();
    return openDatabase(
      join(path, 'medications.db'),
      version: 1,
      onCreate: _createDatabase,
    );
  }

  Future<void> _createDatabase(Database db, int version) async {
    await db.execute('''
      CREATE TABLE medications(
        id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
        name TEXT,
        dosage TEXT,
        frequency TEXT,
        start_date INTEGER,
        end_date INTEGER,
        notes TEXT
      )
    ''');
  }

  Future<int> addMedication(Medication medication) async {
    final db = await database;
    return db.insert('medications', medication.toMap());
  }

  Future<int> updateMedication(Medication medication) async {
    final db = await database;
    return db.update(
      'medications',
      medication.toMap(),
      where: 'id = ?',
      whereArgs: [medication.id],
    );
  }

  Future<int> deleteMedication(int id) async {
    final db = await database;
    return db.delete(
      'medications',
      where: 'id = ?',
      whereArgs: [id],
    );
  }

  Future<List<Medication>> getMedications() async {
    final db = await database;
    final List<Map<String, dynamic>> medicationData = await db.query('medications');
    return medicationData.map((data) => Medication.fromMap(data)).toList();
  }
}
```

Provider Code:

```
import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';
import 'package:medbuddy/models/medication_model.dart';
import 'package:medbuddy/utils/database_helper.dart';

class MedicationProvider extends ChangeNotifier {
  List<Medication> _medications = [];

  List<Medication> get medications => _medications;

  DatabaseHelper database = DatabaseHelper._privateConstructor();

  void addMedication(Medication medication) async {
    _medications.add(medication);
    notifyListeners();
    final db = await database.database;
    await db.insert('medications', medication.toMap());
  }

  void updateMedication(Medication medication) async {
    final index = _medications.indexWhere((element) => element.id == medication.id);
    _medications[index] = medication;
    notifyListeners();
    final db = await database.database;
    await db.update('medications', medication.toMap(), where: 'id = ?', whereArgs: [medication.id]);
  }

  Future<void> deleteMedication(String id) async {
    _medications.removeWhere((element) => element.id == id);
    notifyListeners();
    final db = await database.database;
    await db.delete('medications', where: 'id = ?', whereArgs: [id]);
  }

  Future<void> loadMedications() async {
    final db = await database.database;
    final List<Map<String, dynamic>> medicationData = await db.query('medications');
    _medications = medicationData.map((data) => Medication.fromMap(data)).toList();
    notifyListeners();
  }

  Future<void> init() async {
    await loadMedications();
  }
}
```

I am creating an instance of database class using constructor defined there, but it is not working.

Answer (score 0):

In your provider class `MedicationProvider`, you should use `DatabaseHelper .instance` as it is singleton.

```
  DatabaseHelper database = DatabaseHelper.instance;
```

`_privateConstructor` is private constructor, and not able to accessed outside the file.